# AsyncHttpClient JSON onSuccess function is not getting executed

Tags: java, android, json, android-async-http

My application can't seem to run my onSuccess method.

It says in the log: "W/JsonHttpRH: onSuccess(int, Header[], JSONArray) was not overriden, but callback was received"

A lot of people use JSONArray instead of JSONObject, but this is not the case with me. The code is:

```
private void fetchDictionary() {

    client = new DictionaryClient();
    client.getWords("awesome", new JsonHttpResponseHandler() {

        @Override
        public void onSuccess(int statusCode, Header[] headers, JSONObject response) {

            try {

                JSONArray docs = null;
                if(response != null) {

                    // Get the docs json array
                    docs = response.getJSONArray("docs");
                    // Parse json array into array of model objects
                    final ArrayList<Word> words = Word.fromJson(docs);
                    // Remove all words from the adapter
                    wordAdapter.clear();
                    // Load model objects into the adapter
                    for (Word word : words) {
                        wordAdapter.add(word); // add word through the adapter
                    }
                    wordAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                // Invalid JSON format, show appropriate error.
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
}
```

I'm using http://dictionaryapi.net/ as an API. My URL looks like: "http://dictionaryapi.net/api/definition/awesome" which returns a JSON object.

Answer (score 0):

> My URL looks like: "http://dictionaryapi.net/api/definition/awesome"
>   which returns a JSON object.

That is not true. What you linked returns

```
[{
  "Word": "awesome",
  "PartOfSpeech": "adjective",
  "Forms": [],
  "Definitions": [
    "Causing awe; appalling; awful; as, an awesome sight.",
    "Expressive of awe or terror."
  ]
}]
```

which is an Array filled with one object. You should probably get this array and then get the first element of it.

Answer (score 0):

if i look into json in http://dictionaryapi.net/api/definition/awesome , it will return jsonArray (not jsonObject) without key "docs" :

```
[{
  "Word": "awesome",
  "PartOfSpeech": "adjective",
  "Forms": [],
  "Definitions": [
    "Causing awe; appalling; awful; as, an awesome sight.",
    "Expressive of awe or terror."
  ]
}]
```

use `onSuccess(int statusCode, Header headers[], JSONArray success)` to catch jsonArray return from your URL .